# Regular expression to check the text contents

Tags: r, regex

How to check if a variable is below text in R? An if condition should return true if the var has same text with any number.

```
"Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[33][bigTable=?] in task 'Stage-3:MAPRED' is a cross product"
```

Below texts can be any number.

```
[33] and Stage-3
```

I know I need to use regular expression, but I am very new to regex.

Below is a sample code. Irrespective of number inside the text it should return true.

```
 var == "Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[][bigTable=?] in task 'Stage-:MAPRED' is a cross product"
 var2== "Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[11][bigTable=?] in task 'Stage-13:MAPRED' is a cross product"
 var3== "Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[100][bigTable=?] in task 'Stage-123:MAPRED' is a cross product"
 var4== "Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[11][bigTable=?] in task 'Stage-13:MAPRED' is a cross product-Textadded"
            if (var== var2){return TRUE} #Should return true
            if (var== var3){return TRUE} #Should return true
            if (var== var4){return TRUE} #Should NOT return true
```

Comment: dont really understand what you want. Can you put expected output?

Comment: modified to add a sample code

Comment: what is inside `var` ?

Comment: @boski Sorry for the confusion. var has the same text. But different number for [33] may be [100] or Stage-12 may be Stage-20 etc.. But if rest of the pattern and the text characters are all the same. then it should return true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var="Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[10][bigTable=?] in task 'Stage-12:MAPRED' is a cross product"
var2="Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[33][bigTable=?] in task 'Stage-3:MAPRED' is a cross product"
if (gsub("[0-9]","",var)==gsub("[0-9]","",var2) ){
  print(TRUE)
}
TRUE
```

Use `gsub` to change all numbers to nothing, then compare.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
grepl("\\[\\d+\\].*Stage-\\d+", string)
#[1] TRUE
```

This looks for any number in square brackets `[]` followed by `Stage-` and any number.

**data**

```
string <- "Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[33][bigTable=?] in task 'Stage-3:MAPRED' is a cross product"
```